# DolphinDB: How to delete all the records in the middle of the table?

Tags: database, dolphindb

When I use DolphinDB, I wonder that if there are 3 or more consecutive identical records in both the a and b columns of the table, how can I delete all the records in the middle?

For example：

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods:

```
select * from t where (x -> x == 1 or (next deltas x) < 0)(segmentby(x -> 1..size(x), a, a)) and (x -> x ==1 or (next deltas x) < 0)(segmentby(x -> 1..size(x), b, b))
```

or

```
select * from t where each(def(x,y): x==1 or x==y, segmentby(x -> 1..size(x), a, a), segmentby(size, a, a)) and each(def(x,y): x==1 or x==y, segmentby(x -> 1..size(x), b, b), segmentby(size, b, b))
```